# Why wls_filter generate white flash

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, stereo-3d

I am using opencv 3.4 and python 3.
I have a real-time video from an usb stereo camera with which I performed SGBM stereo match and then I  applied a wls filter as following:

```
#setting filter parameters
lmbda = 80000
sigma = 1.2
visual_multiplier = 1.0
wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=stereoMatcher)
wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

# # Using the WLS filter
np.uint8(dispL)
filteredImg= wls_filter.filter(dispL,grayLeft,None,dispR)
filteredImg = cv2.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=1, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
```

The video I obtain is quite good, but the problem is that I receive frames of video which are totally white, like flesh in the image. 
Why does this happen and there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: Hello, did you get to solve the flash issue? I'm encountering the same exact problem and I would like to know if you were able to fix it or not

Comment: no i m sorry i didn't

Comment: I will try to work on it and will report here results as I have them

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. I used the default wls filter by `cv.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilterGeneric(False)` instead. It gave me a proper result but not ideal.